# Shuffled image of set

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

A permutation $\psi: S \rightarrow S$, where $S = \{1,2,\dots,n\}$, is considered $\textit{descriptive}$ if for every $k < n$, the image under $\psi$ of $\{1,2,\dots,k\}$ is not simply $\{1,2,\dots,k\}$.

Determine the total number of $\textit{descriptive}$ permutations for the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

$\textbf{Analytical Journey:}$

- $\textbf{Initial Observation:}$ It was identified that a critical condition for a permutation to be well-shuffled is $\psi(a_1) \neq a_1$. This observation suggested a strategy of partitioning based on the placement of elements, leading to an exploration of permutations excluding fixed points.
- $\textbf{Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion Strategy:}$ The Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion was considered to remove permutations that are not well-shuffled from the total count of $15!$. The complexity arose in correctly identifying and subtracting permutations by their fixed points to avoid double-counting.
- $\textbf{Recurrence Relation Formulation:}$ A recurrence relation approach was investigated to express the number of well-shuffled permutations for $n$ based on smaller instances. The challenge was in developing a relationship that incorporates the increasing complexity of the well-shuffled condition as $n$ grows.
- $\textbf{Investigation of Generating Functions:}$ Generating functions were explored as a potential method to encapsulate the enumeration problem. The main hurdle was devising a function that naturally excluded permutations that did not meet the well-shuffled criterion, and translating this condition into mathematical terms was particularly challenging.
- $\textbf{Pattern Identification through Smaller Cases:}$ By manually enumerating cases for smaller $n$, an effort was made to uncover patterns that might lead to a method applicable to larger instances. Although this process provided insight, it did not lead to an easily scaled method.

Comment: When you tried small cases, how many permutations were there?

Comment: @CalvinLin It varied for the smaller input values.

Comment: Very interesting approaches, I really wonder whether generating function solution could exist or not.

Comment: Can you provide the values for smaller n? I want to check if I'm on the right track.

Comment: It also implies $\phi(n)\ne n$.

Comment: This is [OEIS sequence A356291](https://oeis.org/A356291), the number of “reducible” permutations. The complement, the “connected”, “indecomposable” or “irreducible” permutations ([OEIS sequence A003319](https://oeis.org/A003319)) seems to be more popular; it has a much lower OEIS sequence number and far more information in the OEIS entry. (And to answer your specific question, the count for $n=15$ is $184078090137$.)

Comment: @joriki You should transform your excellent comment (which gives a maximal information) into an answer. Otherwise, the risk is that this question will remain "officialy" as non-answered.

Comment: @joriki I totally agree with Jean Marie, you should convert this comment into an answer post to receive some credits for contributing to the solution. Each of us would appreciate a detailed outline of your proof outline sketch.

Comment: @joriki Can you please post a detailed solution for this question?

Comment: I’m not sure why everyone here seems to think that I have a proof or a solution :-) I just wrote some code to find the numbers up to $n=12$ so I could search for the OEIS entry and posted the OEIS entry that I found. It has loads of literature references and formulas. I doubt that I’ll be able to add anything to that body of knowledge. I’ll be happy to post my comment as an answer as @JeanMarie suggested, if that would be an acceptable answer to you, but it would be just that, not a proof or a detailed solution. (I could also provide the code if you’re interested in that.)

Comment: @joriki Yes, just post your comment (The code  can be of interest as well...)

Comment: @JeanMarie: I want to hear from the OP whether that would be an acceptable answer, because they were apparently under the impression that I have a proof sketch to contribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a_n$ be the number of descriptive permutations on $\{1,\dots,n\}$. You can prove that, for all $n\ge 1$,
$$
a_n=n!-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k!\cdot a_{n-k}\tag1
$$
This recurrence relation allows you to compute the entire list $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5, a_{6}$ one at a time. Since $6$ is small enough, this is doable by hand.

The sequence $a_n$ is in OEIS, where the above recurrence is given: https://oeis.org/A003319.

*Proof of (1):* For each $k\in \{1,\dots,n-1\}$, let $E_k$ be the set of permutations, $\phi$, with the property that $\phi(\{1,\dots,k\})=k$, but $\phi(\{1,\dots,\ell\})\neq \{1,\dots,\ell\}$ for any $\ell>k$. In words, $E_k$ is the set of permutations for which the largest prefix preserved by the permutation is $\{1,\dots,k\}$.

Note that the sets $E_1,\dots, E_{n-1}$ are disjoint, and every permutation which is *not* well-mixed lies in $E_k$ for some $k$. Therefore,
$$
a_n=n!-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}|E_k|
$$
All that remains is to prove $|E_k|=k!\cdot a_{n-k}$. Given $\phi\in E_k$, certainly $\phi(\{1,\dots,k\})=\{1,\dots,k\}$, so there are $k!$ ways to choose the list $(\phi(1),\dots,\phi(k))$. Furthermore, the list $(\phi(k+1),\phi(k+1),\dots,\phi(n))$ has the property that, for all $\ell\in \{k+1,\dots,n\}$, that
$$
\phi(\{k+1,k+2,\dots,\ell\})\neq \{k+1,k+2,\dots,\ell\}.\tag2
$$
Indeed, if an $\ell$ existed satisfying the above, then we would have $\phi(\{1,\dots,\ell\})=\{1,\dots,\ell\}$, contradicting the definition of $E_k$. Now, if we define $\tilde\phi:\{1,\dots,n-k\}\to \{1,\dots,n-k\}$ by
$$
\tilde\phi(x)=\phi(x+k),
$$
then we see that $(2)$ is equivalent to $\tilde\phi$ being well-mixed. Therefore, there are $a_{n-k}$ to choose the list $(\phi(k+1),\dots,\phi(n))$. This completes the proof that $|E_k|=k!\cdot a_{n-k}$.